# Lebesgue measure nested sequences

Tags: analysis

I am asked to prove the following:

Let $E \subset \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable. Then there is a sequence of open sets $(O_n)$ and a sequence of closed sets $(F_n)$ such that $F_n \subset E \subset O_n$, $F_n \subset F_{n+1}$ and $O_{n+1} \subset O_n$ for all $n$. Furthermore $\lambda((\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty O_n) \setminus (\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n))=0$.

My attempt goes along the lines of this:

Since $E$ is measurable there exists an open set $O_k$ and a closed set $F_k$ such that $F_k \subset E \subset O_k$ where $\lambda(O_k \setminus E)$ and $\lambda(E \setminus F_k)$ can be made "controllably" small. Now I set $O = \limsup O_k$ and $F \liminf F_k$ to get the nestedness. However I am not able to "connect the dots" and get to the last equality (the measure result). Am I onto something here?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $O = \cap_n O_n$ and $F = \cup_n F_n$. Let $k \ge 1$. Then

- $F_k \subset F \subset E \subset O \subset O_k$,
- $O \setminus F \subset O_k \setminus F_k$, and
- $O_k \setminus F_k = (O_k \setminus E) \cup (E \setminus F_k)$.

Thus $\lambda(O \setminus F) \le \lambda(O_k \setminus F_k) \le \lambda(O_k \setminus E) + \lambda(E \setminus F_k)$. Now let $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Are you mixing $k$ and $n$ here? Also, I cannot see how this ensures that the sequences are nested?

Comment: Use the fact that finite intersections of open sets are open and finite unions of closed sets are closed to assume without loss of generality that the sequences are nested.

Comment: Crystal clear! Thank you for your time.